# CSV import and manipulation in Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am new to Python, and trying to take a CSV file that has the following:

```
Computers,price
comp1,150
comp2,250
comp3,100
comp4,175
comp5,60
```

I am trying to read this data (using import CSV module) then I want to remove any computer that are priced below 125, then I want to add a column called quality.
for the remaining computers, I want to set the data in the new column to either high or average based on the following

```
if price is <= 175 
    the price = average 
    else price = High
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
#python 3.7

# Program to read input and out a new file with changes based on conditions

import csv

  with open('c:\computers.csv', 'r') as input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as 
      output:
      csv_input = csv.reader(input)
      csv_output = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')

# keep only computers 125 or over

csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))

for cols in csv_input:
  if float(cols[2]) <=125:
    csv_output.writerows(cols)

#Create new Column called Quality

headers = reader.next()
headers.append('Quality')
writer.writerow(headers)

# Check price and set Quality Column to Average if price <= 175 otherwise set to High
```

Here is where I am at so far. I think I need to do an if  else but not sure how to have it lookup the price column and if that is <=175 append (I assume) to that row in the quality column as average, else append to quality column as High.

Again, I am new, so I hope I don't get blasted too much here.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want:

```
for cols in csv_input:
  if float(cols[2]) >125:
    if float(cols[2]) >175:
      cols[3]='High'
    else:
      cols[3]='Average'
    csv_output.writerows(cols)
```

put the header section before this